# Is it okay to put all datas in cookies or localStorage instead stores in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I got some questions about stores and cookies(or localstroage)

I want the datas that I got from the server(access token, username ...) persist, so that I can make the user be logged even if the refresh event acts in browser. But if I put the datas in the store it could be erased by the refresh event.

So I wanted to put all datas in cookies or localstorage, well is it okay to put all datas in here?
Is there any advantages(like speed?) to put some datas in stores and just renew them when the refresh event occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not cookies! You can use stores for data caching, which is just javascript memory allocated to the user's browser that is globally accessible and reactive. You can also, alternatively, use a normal object declared at the root/top level of your app (which therefore always exists) and pass accessor functions down via props to child components to use to read/write to the cache. I take it a step further and make all database queries go through that caching layer, so that I can satisfy the query from cache memory if we already have the data, and only pass it on to the database if we don't.